# How to wait until all viewmodel asynchronous operations are done

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I need to execute something in my view after all of the asynchronous fetches has been done , for this I have a home framgnet that fetches 3 different sections in my backend

```
  private fun populateSectionA(){
        viewModel.fetchSectionA.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when(it){
                is Resource.Loading -> { //Handling loading }

                is Resource.Success -> {
                  //Handles data
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> { //Error handling }
            }
        })
    }

   private fun populateSectionB(){
        viewModel.fetchSectionB.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when(it){
                is Resource.Loading -> { //Handling loading }

                is Resource.Success -> {
                  //Handles data
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> { //Error handling }
            }
        })
    }

   private fun populateSectionC(){
        viewModel.fetchSectionC.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when(it){
                is Resource.Loading -> { //Handling loading }

                is Resource.Success -> {
                  //Handles data
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> { //Error handling }
            }
        })
    }
```

Here are my observers in my view, what I need to know is when all of these 3 has finished to load my UI

From my viewmodel the fetch is the same for the three sections

```
    val fetchSectionA = liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
                emit(Resource.Loading())
                try {
                    emit(repo.fetchSectionA(sectionId))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    emit(Resource.Failure(e))
                }
            }

 val fetchSectionB = liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            try {
                emit(repo.fetchSectionB(sectionId))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            }
        }

 val fetchSectionC = liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            try {
                emit(repo.fetchSectionC(sectionId))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(Resource.Failure(e))
            }
        }
```

Now, how can I know when all of these individual fetches has been done ? I dont want to use a counter in my UI that counts to certain number untill its reached, instead I would love to give a callback to my UI when all these operations finishes

Comment: use `MediatorLiveData`, add all sections as sources and emit progress based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following code:

```
fun <T1, T2, T3> combineTuple(f1: LiveData<T1>, f2: LiveData<T2>, f3: LiveData<T3>): LiveData<Triple<T1?, T2?, T3?>> = MediatorLiveData<Triple<T1?, T2?, T3?>>().also { mediator ->
    mediator.value = Triple(f1.value, f2.value, f3.value)

    mediator.addSource(f1) { t1: T1? ->
        val (_, t2, t3) = mediator.value!!
        mediator.value = Triple(t1, t2, t3)
    }

    mediator.addSource(f2) { t2: T2? ->
        val (t1, _, t3) = mediator.value!!
        mediator.value = Triple(t1, t2, t3)
    }

    mediator.addSource(f3) { t3: T3? ->
        val (t1, t2, _) = mediator.value!!
        mediator.value = Triple(t1, t2, t3)
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
combineTuple(fetchSectionA, fetchSectionB, fetchSectionC)
    .map { (sectionA, sectionB, sectionC) ->
        val sectionA = sectionA.takeIf { it != Resource.Loading } ?: return@map null
        val sectionB = sectionB.takeIf { it != Resource.Loading } ?: return@map null
        val sectionC = sectionC.takeIf { it != Resource.Loading } ?: return@map null

        return Triple(sectionA, sectionB, sectionC)
    }
```

If you need more or less arity combiners for LiveData, check https://github.com/Zhuinden/livedata-combinetuple-kt

Comment: then from my UI when I objserve I can access these sections as the list they return like triple.first , triple.second, triple.third , is that right ?

Comment: Of course, but it's even cooler if you use decomposition